# How to get the single value from the array?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter-3

I am using CodeIgnator. I am returning the `$result = $query->result();` from the model

**Controller**

```
$get_cust_previous_info=$this->Customer_model->get_cust_previous_info($cust_mob);

echo"<pre>";
print_r($get_cust_previous_info);
echo "</pre>";
```

I am getting the array value

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [cust_id] => 8
            [c_b_id] => 8
        )

)
```

1) Now I have to assign the cust_id and c_b_id value
something like

```
$cust=$get_cust_previous_info['cust_id'];
$c_b=$get_cust_previous_info['c_b_id'];
```

2) Some time I am also returning the row `$result = $query->row();` from model

**Getting array**

```
stdClass Object
(
    [cust_id] => 8
    [c_b_id] => 8
)

$cust=$get_cust_previous_info['cust_id'];
$c_b=$get_cust_previous_info['c_b_id'];
```

How to get the cust_id and c_b_id value? because I have to assign the single value to the variable.

would you help me out in this?

Comment: @Chris, What about the second issues?

Comment: you need to add INDEX $cust=$get_cust_previous_info[index]['cust_id'];
$c_b=$get_cust_previous_info[index]['c_b_id']; index value is your array index such as 0,1,2,3 and so on..

Comment: @IamCavic, something like this $get_cust_previous_info[0]['cust_id'];   right?

Comment: yes that is correct, you need to know the position so if you have more than 1 element you can get the lengths of it and loop over them one by one or if you only ever get one to work with than you can hard code 0

Comment: @IamCavic, that's cool! Thanks

Comment: 1. point -> $cust=$get_cust_previous_info[0]->cust_id;
2. point -> $cust=$get_cust_previous_info->cust_id;